# Detecting drop event on kineticjs from outside elements

Tags: jquery, kineticjs

I need to detect a drop event on a kineticjs canvas of an element being dragged from outside the canvas (a line from a select/listbox).

There are plenty of drag and drop examples for kineticjs elements within the canvas, but how do I detect drops from outside elements, particularly the drop coordinates?

Any dnd help from JQuery is highly encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code to drop an outside element into a canvas and report the drop coordinates:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #dragMe{border:3px solid blue; width:60px; background-color:cyan; line-height:30px;}
    canvas{border:3px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    function allowDrop(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    function drag(ev){
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    }
    function drop(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        alert("You dropped [#"+data+"] in the canvas at: X="+ev.clientX+" and Y="+ev.clientY);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Drag the text to the red canvas</p>
    <canvas id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></canvas>
    <br>
    <p id="dragMe" src="house-icon.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Drag Me</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that does it - and even in plain HTML. Thanks! There is a live demo here, which is partially working: http://jsfiddle.net/jensk/5MZR7/  The Javascript is apparently declared after the HTML in jsfiddle.

Comment: Updated the live preview code to work as the code above by using unobtrusive JQuery JS: http://jsfiddle.net/jensk/5MZR7/  

The clientX/Y positions from the event seems to be relative to the window/iFrame. How do I get the canvas' X/Y position from within the event handler, so i can subtract them?

Comment: To get the canvas position relative to the document, use $("#myCanvas").offset() and then access the .Left and .Top properties.

Comment: the fiddle is not working @jensk :( can't drag and drop

Comment: @Sahar. This question relates to getting the drop x/y coordinates, not how to create a new element upon drop ;-)